# Do hstore and jsonb have the same plumbing internally?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Is `hstore` internally implemented identically as `jsonb`, just with a constraint that the data must be flat? If not, when/why should hstore be used instead of jsonb?

Comment: hstore existed (as an extension) long before json or jsonb were introduced. So I very much doubt they use the same internal code. Nowadays I would always prefer JSONB over hstore

Comment: [This](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/) might throw some more light on the matter - it would appear that internally, JSONB and HStore are similar `Finally in Postgres 9.4 we got real and proper JSON in the form of JSONB. The B stands for better. JSONB is a binary representation of JSON, this means it’s compressed and more efficient for storage than just text. It also has a similar plumbing of hstore underneath. In fact, once upon a time there was almost hstore2 and a separate JSON type, but the two converged into the JSONB we have today.`